# AJAX - get_posts for a specific post type returns empty

Tags: ajax, get-posts

I'm trying to load more posts via an ajax call but the array always returns empty.

To troubleshoot, I replaced the "testimonial" in "get_posts" with "post" and "application" (another custom post type) and both worked fine.

At the same time, when I test the same "get_posts" function directly on the page and print_r the result, it returns the testimonials as it should. But when the same function is performed via ajax, it comes back empty.

I'm totally lost how to solve it and will be gratefull for any suggestion.

jQuery part:

```
        var showMoreBtn = $('#show_more');

        showMoreBtn.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                action: 'ajax_show_more_testims',   
                max: <?php echo $max; ?>,
                security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("show-more"); ?>',
            }

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                var responseData = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(responseData);
            });
        });
```

AJAX:

````
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_show_more_testims', 'ajax_show_more_testims');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_show_more_testims', 'ajax_show_more_testims');

function ajax_show_more_testims() {
    check_ajax_referer('show-more', 'security');

    $max = (int) $_POST['max'];

    $testims = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'testimonial',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ));

    echo json_encode($testims);

    wp_die();
}```
````

Comment: Is your jQuery part a seperate js-file? If yes, you can't use PHP in there, if not, you can't use ajaxurl.

Comment: The jQuery script is in the same file as the rest of the code, no problem there.The whole thing works like a charm if I try to retrieve another post type. The problem only appears when I try to retrieve posts of the testimonial post type. Which makes me think that it has something to do with the settings of the testimonial post type, but from what I see it is the same as, for example, applicaitons, which I can easily retrieve with this code.